# Map step lambda function with empty event is running a keyerror

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, etl, aws-step-functions

I'm writing a step function where lambda A queries a database and creates an array with s3bucket/s3key dictionaries for each one that needs to be processed.
For the processing I have a Map state that takes this s3bucket/s3key and do some processing.

For some reason, the event is coming empty resulting in an error in the Map state execution:

Here is the step function definition

```
{
  "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using Pass states",
  "StartAt": "QueryTable",
  "States": {
    "QueryTable",": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:...function:query_table:$LATEST"
      },
       "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Next": "ProcessDocuments"
    },
    "ProcessDocuments": {
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.toprocess",
      "MaxConcurrency": 5,
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "Process",
        "States": {
          "Process": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:...:...:function:process:$LATEST"
            },
            "End": true
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

And the error

```
{
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "error": "KeyError",
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "'s3bucket'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "stackTrace": [
      "  File \"/var/task/process.py\", line 260, in lambda_handler\n    raise e\n",
      "  File \"/var/task/process.py\", line 230, in lambda_handler\n    s3bucket, s3key = extract_event_data(event)\n",
      "  File \"/var/task/process.py\", line 125, in extract_event_data\n    bucket = record['s3bucket']\n"
    ]
  }
}
```

I read the ItemsPath and InputPath documentation. Also, used [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-map-state.html) to see if I was using it incorrectly but it was no use.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the issue?
- Do you have difficulty returning array from Lambda and then pass it to Map state?
- Or the issue is how to handle empty result from Lambda Task state?

Comment: Hi @PooyaParidel the issue was that the event received was empty and it should not. We fixed it I will post the fix here later. It was the Parameters in the Iterator cleaning the event.